# InvalidOperationException was unhandled.. I'm not seeing the logic error? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, module

As a newbie to VB.Net, very casual programmer. i am struggling to find the logic error in this statement. It says I am recursively calling the Form, but I don't see it.

I have a created new module outside of the Form class where I am initialising all my functions from. In this function I request the text data from a few textboxes.

```
' ----- A function within a module -----
Private Function run_stress_function()
    'Building my class
    Dim req_width As New Pocket_Stress_Function(CDbl(frmMain.txtPBend.Text),
                                                CDbl(frmMain.txtPAllow.Text),
                                                CDbl(frmMain.txtPthick.Text),
                                                CDbl(frmMain.txtPwidth.Text), 1.5)
    Return req_width.Flange_width
End Function
```

Can you help me with the logic. Later on in the same module I call this line in a sub:

```
Dim scrX As Integer = frmMain.pnlDraw.Size.Width
```

And that work perfectly? So I seem to be missing the logic. Help?

Error Details (note this come out of new module, hence I can't use Me.):

System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The form referred to itself during construction from a default instance, which led to infinite recursion.  Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using 'Me.'

Comment: It is talking about code in the `Sub New` procedure in the form.  not that stress function.  That thing could receive 4 Doubles though rather than referencing the form (and apparently using a default instance)

Comment: I found that when the form is getting called it calls the module from    `Private Sub txtPthick_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
            Pocket_Link_to_Form()`
So @Plutonix technically your second assessment was correct. My next question is why is the form loading and calling **textbox__TextChanged**

Answer (score 0):

Your exception message says it all

> Within the Form's constructor refer to the form using **'Me.'**

Use it this way (replace frmMain with Me)

```
Private Function run_stress_function()
    Dim req_width As New Pocket_Stress_Function(CDbl(Me.txtPBend.Text),
                                                CDbl(Me.txtPAllow.Text),
                                                CDbl(Me.txtPthick.Text),
                                                CDbl(Me.txtPwidth.Text), 1.5)
    Return req_width.Flange_width
End Function
```

Comment: Yeah, No that doesn't work... remember I said that I created a new Module... So I am outside the Form Class.. Thus "Me." =  Error BC32001

Comment: In that case you may pass it (`Me`) as an argument from the calling form and add a form type parameter to the `run_stress_function`.

Comment: I guess I can pass the form throught the module. But it doesn't explain why later on I can directly reference to Dim scrX As Integer = frmMain.pnlDraw.Size.Width in the same module but different sub.

Comment: time is a factor.  it depends *when* these things are being called.

Comment: Is the base logic incorrect, should I not be passing form control data outside of the form class directly?

Comment: That all depends your logic, event sequence. From where and in what context you are calling your function (run_stress_function) and whether the form (frmMain) is already loaded or not etc. Your description of what you are trying to accomplish may help other assist you in a better way.

Comment: Ok... so frmMain calls Pocket_Link_to_Form() which calls the run_stress_function()

The weird thing is I have a whole bunch of later functions that work, It's just this one that doesn't e.g. of those that work in the same module diff sub.
**Dim scrY As Integer = frmMain.pnlDraw.Size.Height**